# Play each scene at godot 3.1

Tags: godot, scene, scene2d

I have created a project.
And I have saved 20 scenes for 20 game levels.
I have designed each scene but when I hit f5 to play each scene, it shows level1 scene.
I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Have you written [code to change scenes](https://godotengine.org/qa/24773/how-to-load-and-change-scenes) when you want to transition to the next one? Show us that code.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to test out a given scene independently, you can use:

- `F6` to play the scene that's currently active in the editor.
- `Control+Shift+F5` to play a custom scene (brings up a selection menu).

By default both of the above should have icons in the upper right hand corner:
[image]

Otherwise, if you want to change the scene via code (for example change to level 2 after level 1 has been completed), there's an [example of changing scenes in the documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.6/tutorials/scripting/scene_tree.html#changing-current-scene):

```
func _my_level_was_completed():
    get_tree().change_scene("res://levels/level2.tscn")
```

Note: the docs I linked are for version 3.6 stable - the most current pre 4th edition at the time of writing this answer. If you want the  3.1 version, you can find that [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/getting_started/step_by_step/scene_tree.html#changing-current-scene). In general, `change_scene` is valid for all 3.x versions of Godot; in Godot 4 you use `change_scene_to_file` instead of `change_scene`.

Note: If you already have code for changing scenes & it's not working, you'll need to edit your post to include that before anyone can attempt to troubleshoot it.

Comment: That `change_scene` example is correct for all Godot 3.x (In Godot 4 you use `change_scene_to_file` instead of `change_scene`). The reason why it could have been difficult to find it in Godot 3.1 documentation is because they moved things around in the documentation, which was for Godot 3.4 I believe. Anyway, here is the example in the documentation for Godot 3.1: [Changing current scene](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/getting_started/step_by_step/scene_tree.html#changing-current-scene).

Comment: @Theraot Awesome info! I've folded that into my answer. I appreciate you taking the time to point that out.